# Configure systemd-network vlans that don't auto-start

Tags: networking, systemd, vlan

**Question**: Under systemd-networkd, how do I configure a VLAN that doesn't automatically come up on system boot?

**Details**:
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 server. My workstation has two network interfaces. eth0 is my main interface, connects to my regular network, and is working as desired. eth1 is connected to a switch trunk port that gives me access to a number of other in-house networks that I occasionally use for development or testing purposes. I have two vlans defined in systemd-networkd (/etc/systemd/network). Each vlan has a bridge defined, for use with various containers or virtual machines.

As configured, eth1 and the vlans come up automatically on reboot. Since I rarely used these vlans or bridges, so I'd like them to stay down until I manually bring them up. I've tried setting ActivationPolicy=manual, but that only works for physical interfaces, not for vlans.

My current configuration files appear below. Any ideas how I can prevent networkd from bringing up the vlans automatically?

11-eth1.network

```
[Match]
Name=eth1
MACAddress=[obscured]

[Link]
ActivationPolicy=manual

[Network]
VLAN=vlan22
VLAN=vlan24
```

12-eth1.netdev

```
[NetDev]
Name=eth1
Kind=vlan
MACAddress=[obscured]
```

21-vlan22.netdev

```
[NetDev]
Name=vlan22
Kind=vlan

[VLAN]
Id=22
```

22-vlan24.netdev

```
[NetDev]
Name=vlan24
Kind=vlan

[VLAN]
Id=24
```

31-vlan22.network

```
[Match]
Name=vlan22

[Network]
Bridge=br22
DHCP=yes
```

32-vlan24.network

```
[Match]
Name=vlan24

[Network]
Bridge=br24
DHCP=yes
```

41-br22.netdev

```
[NetDev]
Name=br22
Kind=bridge
```

42-br24.netdev

```
[NetDev]
Name=br24
Kind=bridge
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue myself. I needed `systemd-networkd` to create a lot of VLANs that I would later manage from another application. For some reason, neither `ActivationPolicy=manual` nor `ActivationPolicy=down` shut the interfaces down; instead, `systemd-networkd` just ignores it on VLANs and leaves the interface up. I suspect what is happening is that the VLAN interface comes up by default, and `systemd-network` does not actively shut it down.

I got around this issue by creating a trigger service that runs when the VLAN interface goes up, immediately shutting it down, again. Since my VLANs are not managed by a `systemd-networkd` `.network` file (`ActivationPolicy=manual`), they stay down.

First, create a helper .service file as `/lib/systemd/system/iface-forced-shutdown@.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Interface Forced Shutdown Service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=ip link set %i down

[Install]
WantedBy=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
```

Notice that this is a template that can be used with any interface.

Finally, for any interface you want to be automatically shutdown, enable the corresponding service:

```
systemctl enable iface-forced-shutdown@eth0.5
systemctl enable iface-forced-shutdown@eth0.60
```

A couple of caveats:

- The link may technically go up for a few milliseconds, before going back down. This may or may not be a security concern for you.
- I'm not 100% sure that there isn't a narrow race condition between `systemd-networkd` bringing the interface up, and `iface-forced-shutdown@.service` shutting it down (.. which could lead to the interface staying up).

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue of "For some reason, neither ActivationPolicy=manual nor ActivationPolicy=down shut the interfaces down". No ideia why this happens.

Comment: Issue fixed here https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/22593

Comment: @TCB13 that's great! thanks for reporting this issue to the systemd folks!